# What specific species of grasshopper is this, and is it an invasive species that I should kill?

Tags: bugs, bug-identification, invasive-species

I just discovered a huge (6-8 cm, ~3 inches) insect in our potted Astilbe plant. As far as I can tell it's a grasshopper but I don't know which kind exactly. From what I can find in the [Dutch species register](https://www.nederlandsesoorten.nl/linnaeus_ng/app/views/species/nsr_taxon.php?id=169830&cat=CTAB_MEDIA), it looks the most like a *Tettigonia viridissima*, but the [section on identifying](https://www.nederlandsesoorten.nl/linnaeus_ng/app/views/species/nsr_taxon.php?id=169858&cat=151) those says they are 30-35mm long, the one I found is definitely double that size, since it was as long (a bit longer even) than my thumb when stretched out.

Most grasshopper species I know (and have seen) in The Netherlands are smaller, which makes me suspect I may be dealing with an invasive species, and I might be better off killing it now, because it looks like it was laying eggs. Before just killing it though, I'd like to make sure I haven't missed anything, and I would appreciate some help in identifying this insect. Below is the best picture I have of it, which is most true to it's actual color and shows the entire insect. I took a few other shots as well: [a close-up of the head](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYjmf.jpg), [a close-up of it's backside showing differently colored stripes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsWDU.jpg), and [a picture from the side, which I suspect shows it's laying eggs?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1oz7.jpg).

**Can anyone identify this species for me, and if this is an invasive species?**

[image: Image of suspected grasshopper]

Comment: I wonder if this may get better answers on [Gardening.SE].

Comment: @gerrit I'd be more than happy to move sites if needed, I had a tough time picking a specific site... Besides [gardening.se] it seems there are also questions on [biology.se] about identifying insects... So I went with this one since it's the only one that seems to have a [tag:bug-identification] tag :D

Answer (score 2):

Long-horned grasshopper or Great green bush-cricket(Tettigonia viridissima)

https://www.britannica.com/topic/long-horned-grasshopper-2096594
The image on this page looks almost identical to yours, and it is a female if I read the page correctly so it could well be laying eggs. They're native everywhere but Antarctica, though most common in the tropics.

Comment: Yeah, it really does look like a *Tettigonia viridissima*, but like I said in the question, the Dutch species register seems to rule that one out: their identification section says they're about 30-35mm long, the one in this picture was a bit longer than my thumb, so it was probably between 60-80mm long. I don't see any measurements on the Britannica page though :|

Comment: @Tinkeringbell if you follow through to the full article it says they can be over 6cm

Comment: I have a bit of trouble navigating, but you mean [this page](https://www.britannica.com/animal/long-horned-grasshopper)? That's about katydids, which still leaves ~6000 options for a distinct species, and as many options for size (range of 1 to over 6 cm)... I don't see any data specific measurement data there on *Tettigonia viridissima* as a species, sadly :( Am I looking at the wrong page?